# i3 xterm menu (ctrl+mouse) too small

Tags: x11, configuration, xterm, i3, menu

I've recently started to use the i3 window manager.
I configured i3 and xterm to fit my needs, but whenever I start xterm and want use the menu (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+`mouse_button`), the menu gets displayed as a small window with no border and no title bar. I can't use the menu, because the options are not visible.
The black border is the one surrounding the menu. As you can see, it displays "VT" ...
[image: screenshot of xterm menu not working]

How can I fix this? Is it something with i3 or Xresources?

**~/.Xdefaults**

```
xterm*dynamicColors:    true
xterm*background:      grey13
xterm*foreground:      yellow
xterm*utf8:             1
xterm*eightBitInput:    true
xterm*saveLines:        32767
xterm*scrollTtyKeypress:       true
xterm*scrollTtyOutput:  false
xterm*scrollBar:        true
xterm*loginShell:       true
xterm*font:         7x13
xterm*jumpScroll:       true
xterm*multiScroll:      true
xterm*toolBar:          true
xterm*geometry:                90x30
xterm*cursorBlink:          true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the resource setting for geometry:

```
xterm*geometry:                90x30
```

That applies to the VT100 window and the menus — using different units of measure.  For the VT100, it is *characters*, but for the menu it is *pixels*.  Pixels are a lot smaller than (most) characters.

You probably meant this:

```
xterm*VT100.geometry:          90x30
```

Further reading: *[Why are the menus tiny?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#tiny_menus)* (xterm FAQ)